# undefined method `premails_path' for #<#<Class:0x4fa8530>:0x52c1ec8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I am trying to add a pre-launch sign-up email form on my pages index view. I made a form on my view, then created a controller, then made the model and table and ran the migration. Is this the right way to do it?

I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Pages#index
undefined method `premails_path' for #<#<Class:0x4fa8530>:0x52c1ec8>
```

on line:

```
<%= form_for(@premail) do |f| %>
```

from

```
<%= form_for(@premail) do |f| %>
     <% if @premail.errors.any? %>
       <div id="error_explanation">
         <h2><%= pluralize(@premail.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>
```

My pages controller has the following:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @premail = Premail.new
    end




end
```

My pages index view has the following:

```
<%= form_for(@premail) do |f| %>
  <% if @premail.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@premail.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @premail.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :Email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I generated the following model:

```
class Premail < ActiveRecord::Base


end
```

and the following db migrate table:

```
class CreatePremails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :premails do |t|

        t.text    :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What can I do differently to make this work?

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: try to run 'rake routes' and check the correct routes

Comment: Yep, sounds like you've neglected to add a premails entry in your `config/routes.rb` file

Comment: thanks guys, I forgot to put the resource for premails. Newb mistake, still learning! If you guys post as answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're loading this form on `Pages#index`, you'll benefit from using the [`url:` argument](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) like this:

```
<%= form_for @premail, url: pages_index_path do |f| %>
```

---

**Update**

From the [Rails guide](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for):

> Resource-oriented style
>
> In the examples just shown, although not indicated explicitly, we
>   still need to use the :url option in order to specify where the form
>   is going to be sent. However, further simplification is possible if
>   the record passed to form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to a
>   set of RESTful routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in
>   config/routes.rb. In this case Rails will simply infer the appropriate
>   URL from the record itself. For example,
>
> ```
> <%= form_for @post do |f| %>   ... <% end %> is then equivalent to
> ```
>
> something like:
>
> ```
> <%= form_for @post, as: :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch,
> html: { class: "edit_post", id: "edit_post_45" } do |f| %>   ... <%
> end %>
> ```

As you're using `@premails` instance var (which is an instance of the `Premail` class), your `form_for` helper will be trying to use a `premails` path. To use a `pages` path (as per your question), you'll need to manually set the `url` option

Comment: So I can either state the url explicitly and use one of the pages roots rather than having to add a resource for premail altogether? Is that what it's getting at? I'm new to coding forgive my ignorance if that is incorrect.

Comment: Sure, you're exactly right! The reason I posted my answer is because you're using `pages#index` to show the form. If you use the `form_for` helper as is, you'll find the form tries to load `premails#create` or similar. This would not work for you going off what you posted in your question. It may be what you want, but I only have your question to deal with :)

Comment: Cool, I ended up just adding a resource for premails as others suggested and fixed it. Is that considered poor code if I'm not actually rendering any premail views?

Comment: It depends on your setup. Coding is about efficiency -- is what you've done efficient? If you don't render the views, why do you need the routes?

Comment: No problem - hope my answer helps